# How to convert JSON to Typescript and compare two Typescript types?

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I need to convert JSON to a typescript type or interface and then compare that type or interface with my own to get true or false .

I tried to find some simple way to implement this, but did not find it. Maybe there is some library for such a task, but so far I have not found it.

json and type example

```
{
  "accessToken": "justTestString",
  "logOutToken": "justTestString"
}

export type RootObject = {
        accessToken: string;
        logOutToken: string;
    }
```

Comment: You are looking for creation of a JSON schema, [this](https://github.com/yousefed/typescript-json-schema) is most probably you need!

Comment: TypeScript only does compile-time  type checks. Where is the JSON coming from?

Comment: @Jishan Shaikh how will this help me? I don't need to compare two json . I need to find out what is typing in json as in my type, which I have already written. Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: @beautifulcoder what difference does it make where json comes from? How can this information help? It is written that you need to turn json into a type or interface as in some kind of generator and compare two types or interfaces. It doesn't matter where the json comes from

Answer (score 0):

I am not use to convert JSON, but I would use `typeof`, even if the function can be a bit long depending on the JSON.

In this case :

```
function isMatchingType(obj: any): obj is RootObject {
  return (
    typeof obj === "object" &&
    typeof obj.accessToken === "string" &&
    typeof obj.logOutToken === "string"
  );
}
```

Comment: This is a cool option, but I need an accurate comparison. It is not enough to check that the types that I specify in the function are suitable. It also needs to be nothing else. Therefore, we need to convert JSON to a type or interface in order to compare them. If that's at all possible, of course.